# Number of solutions for 2 equations involving 4 variables

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Given that $a, b, c, d$ are positive integers,
What are the number of solutions for the given 2 equations,

$\mathbf{ad - bc > 0}$
$\mathbf{a + d = n }$
where, $n$ is a given positive integer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\tau(n)$ denote the number of positive divisors of $n$, or equivalently the number of ways to write $n=bc$ with $b,c>0$. Let $T(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{x-1} \tau(n)$. Then the number of solutions is exactly $\sum_{a=1}^{n-1} T\big(a(n-a)\big)$: we must have $a$ between $1$ and $n-1$ inclusive, which fixes the value of $d$; then we must have $bc$ equaling some number $n$ less than $ad=a(n-a)$, and $T(a(n-a)$ counts exactly how many ways this can happen.

There's no particularly nice formula for $T(x)$. It's known that $T(x) \sim x\log x$ when $x$ is large, from which one can deduce that the number of solutions to your problem is $\sim \frac16 n^3\log n$ when $n$ in large.

Comment: But what if n is in the range 10^3 ??

Comment: Then you can just calculate $\tau(n)$ and hence $T(x)$ directly.

Comment: Alternatively, can we find the number of solutions for bc < n where, n is a given integer > 0 and b, c are positive integers.